# Sonar stopped logging messages

Tags: sonarqube

A few days ago I installed an unofficial plugin [sonar-swift](https://github.com/Backelite/sonar-swift).

After restarting Sonar, the logs have thrown an incompatibility issue for the plugin (my SonarQube is old, version 5.4).

I deleted the plugin from the location: *$SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugin*.

Since then, the application starts normally, but Sonar has stopped logging messages (the last log messages are from a few days ago).

Can anyone guess what could have happened? How to fix it?

Comment: This is a strange behaviour. 

In order to help you, here are some questions :

* So you can restart SonarQube and everything is working normally ?
* Is the directory of log files still writable by SonarQube user ?
* What is the level of your log files ?

Comment: What happens if you start SonarQube in the "console mode"? Use `bin/yourOs/sonar.sh console`. Do you see any output?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem by installing SQ 5.4, breaking it by installing the linked sonar-swift, then remove sonar-swift, but I see logs just fine. Which logs are you talking about exactly? I checked `logs/access.log`. Please edit into your question all the details regarding the questions in the comments, and then maybe we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check the $SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties file for log configuration. Perhaps the max number of files has been reached. Also might want to check that the logging directory wasn't changed by the plugin and that it has proper permissions.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Server+Log+Management